# Bash > retrieving array of integer values from text file without duplicates

Tags: linux, bash, shell, text

I have the following script. It correctly returns the first instance of an integer value (File ID) from a text file

```
#!/bin/bash

#create file list
mtp-files > file_list.txt
echo "Hello World"

#retrieve File ID from file list
id=$(awk -F'[ \t]*:[ \t]*' '$1 == "File ID"{print $2; exit}' file_list.txt)

echo "$id"
```

But I need an array containing ALL File ID integers values without duplicates. For example, if the following is my file_list.txt, my script should return an array containing 8,9,10

```
libmtp version: 1.1.10

mtp-files: Successfully connected
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Listing File Information on Device with name: LGE 360 CAM MTP Device
File ID: 8
   Filename: 20161212_095355.jpg
   File size 625762 (0x0000000000098C62) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 9
   Filename: 20161212_095416.jpg
   File size 602264 (0x0000000000093098) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 10
   Filename: 20161212_095520.jpg
   File size 642770 (0x000000000009CED2) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 8
   Filename: 20161212_095355.jpg
   File size 625762 (0x0000000000098C62) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 9
   Filename: 20161212_095416.jpg
   File size 602264 (0x0000000000093098) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 10
   Filename: 20161212_095520.jpg
   File size 642770 (0x000000000009CED2) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 8
   Filename: 20161212_095355.jpg
   File size 625762 (0x0000000000098C62) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 9
   Filename: 20161212_095416.jpg
   File size 602264 (0x0000000000093098) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 10
   Filename: 20161212_095520.jpg
   File size 642770 (0x000000000009CED2) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
OK.
```

Comment: Does the order of the indices need to be preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only to get the IDs, you can reduce your `awk` command like this:

```
awk '/File ID/ { print $3 }' file_list.txt | sort | uniq
```

You still need to use the `sort` and `uniq` commands in order to remove any duplicated result.

The entire command would be:

```
array_of_ids=($(awk '/File ID/ { print $3 }' file_list.txt | sort | uniq))
echo ${array_of_ids[@]}
10 8 9

echo ${array_of_ids[0]}
10
echo ${array_of_ids[1]}
8
echo ${array_of_ids[2]}
9
```

**Extra "(" and ")" surrounding the command ensures you're creating a bash array.

Comment: You can make it slightly simpler (spare one pipe), if you use `sort -u`.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do the trick. You don't need third party tools `sort` and `uniq` to remove duplicates, while `awk` can do that on its own.

```
awk -F'[: ]' '/^File ID/{seen[$2]++;}END{ for (i in seen) print i}' file_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
id=$(awk -F'[ \t]*:[ \t]*' '$1 == "File ID"{print $2; exit}' file_list.txt | sort | uniq)
```